# Does an Otyugh really have 3 melee attacks per round?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, attack

The Otyugh description reads:

> Tentacle, At-Will
>
> Attack: Melee 3 (one creature); +12 vs. AC

The way I read it due to it mentioning "one creature" that its **3 attacks per standard action**. Is this correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

That 3 is actually it's melee *reach*.

A multi attack stat block in 4e looks like:

> Effect: The mooncalf makes three melee attacks, each against a different target.

When you see a power say melee X, the X refers to the reach of the attack. melee 1 is the default, but you might see 0, 2, 3, or more.