# How does an Otyugh move?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, movement

The Otyugh is typically depicted with three legs, three tentacles, and an asymmetric body layout.

While many have asked questions about the Otyugh like [the number of melee attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46090/60557) or [the grapple](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/75989/60557), nobody has asked about how movement itself works. The 5E *Monster Manual* lists a speed in the stat-block, so it must move somehow.

Given its unusual body structure, how does the Otyugh walk – or move, if not by walking?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### It walks with its three legs.

The 5th Edition *Monster Manual* gives an image depicting Otyugh locomotion on pg. 8:

[image]

Reaching into older editions, the 3.5 *Monster Manual* contains this description on pg. 204:

> The creature shuffles about on three thick, sturdy legs

Reaching back further still, *Dragon Magazine #96* published in April of 1985 has a similar description, in the article "The Ecology of Gulguthra" by Ed Greenwood (pg. 21):

> An otyugh's body is lumpy, mottled purple, green, and (primarily) brown, and the creature stumps about on three fat legs of similar appearance.

Comment: There's also the walking animations of the otyugh enemy models from Baldur's Gate 2, off of the top of my head.

Comment: @nick012000 I had started looking for a good video of that, but didn’t find one. If you’ve got one, leave a link in a comment and I’ll see about adding it to the answer.

Comment: Maybe ask the Arqade? The game's been out for decades now and mothers have pretty thoroughly explored it. Maybe someone over there has the expertise to datamine it from the game files

Comment: Not the best view, but here:  https://youtu.be/8Rj6doBTTZI?t=822  ... if the time doesn't work, jump to 13:42.